# log4j2 configuration for Standard Java Project

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm trying to set up log4j2 in a Standard Java Application.

I've logged at many tutorials online but they are all based around using a Maven project where as I am using Standard Vanilla Java using SDK 1.8. The application does not have a Main Class as the starting point as the application is a plugin for another application that executed the built .jar.

I have a log file that would suit my needs and believe I have set up the instance of the Logger in the code correctly.

The configuration file I located in my src folder. Project Structure is as follows:

```
Project Root
    - src
        - UI
        - Errors
            - error classes go here
        - Reports
            - report classes go here
        - Utilities
            - utility classes go here
        - CapitalReportsApplication - (This is the starting point of the application)
        - resources
            - log4j2.xml
```

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Class File Logger Initialisation

```
private static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(CapitalReportsApplication.class.getName());
log.info("This is a message");
```

When running the plugin from the client application, I get all expected results but with no logging file.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you should have something like that. You don't set the type of appender for example.

```
<appender name="rollingFile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${LOG_DIR}/application.log" />
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n" />
        </layout>
</appender>
```

The properties could be like (log4j.properties) :

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=${LOG_DIR}/application.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true

log4j.rootCategory=ALL, rollingFile
```

log4j2.xml  have to be in resources folder, please check

Comment: Unfortunately this has not worked either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Change info to debug:)

Comment: Still no log file output. I've tried the putting the configuration file in every directory in the project and still nothing.

Comment: Could you check Stack trase as well?

Comment: @demonLaMagra  I added one more point to check in the answer, could you check please?

Comment: still no luck although I was missing the resources folder. Updated original question to include that.

Comment: <Root level="debug">   and log.info  could you change it to debug as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186479/discussion-between-demonlamagra-and-echoinacup).